# How does null safe operator works in php 8?

Tags: php, null, operator-keyword, php-8

PHP introduced null operator in PHP8. What is the benefit of using Null operator. And how does it work? Will be delightful in anyone enlighten my knowledge.

Comment: This is the first Google result, https://stitcher.io/blog/php-8-nullsafe-operator. Did you read that already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*What it does* is surely explained in the blog post you found it mentioned in.

*How it works* is best explained by a simple bytecode dump:

```
 L3    #0     JMP_NULL                $null                J5                   @1
 L3    #1     FETCH_OBJ_R             $null                "optional"           ~0
 L3    #2     JMP_NULL                ~0                   J5                   @1
 L3    #3     INIT_METHOD_CALL        ~0                   "maybenull"  
 L3    #4     DO_FCALL  
 L4    #5     RETURN<-1>              1
```

Any occurence of `?->` is represented by an attribute fetch or method call, but preceded with `JMP_NULL`, that would simply skip the remainder of the expression.